# using two _mm_loadl_epi64 over one _mm_load_si128

Tags: c, intel, sse, simd, intrinsics

I need to use 16 bit values(positive values) and promote them to 32 bit.

Using SIMD (I am restricted to SSE3 only), here are the two options I have come up with :

```
reg_xmm0 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)(Src));
reg_xmm2 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)(Src+8));

reg_xmm1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(reg_xmm0,_mm_setzero_si128());
reg_xmm0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg_xmm0,_mm_setzero_si128());
reg_xmm3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi16(reg_xmm2,_mm_setzero_si128());
reg_xmm2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg_xmm2,_mm_setzero_si128());
```

Or I can do like this,

```
reg_xmm0 = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i *)(Src));
reg_xmm1 = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i *)(Src+4));
reg_xmm2 = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i *)(Src+8));
reg_xmm3 = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i *)(Src+12));

reg_xmm0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg_xmm0,_mm_setzero_si128());
reg_xmm1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg_xmm1,_mm_setzero_si128());
reg_xmm2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg_xmm2,_mm_setzero_si128());
reg_xmm3 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(reg_xmm3,_mm_setzero_si128());
```

Which approch should I go for? Will there be any performance improvement using 2nd method over 1st. Please note that I have replaced `_mm_loadu_si128` with two `_mm_loadl_epi64`.

Comment: Why not just try both approaches and benchmark them ? If you're serious about code optimisation then you will already have a test harness for doing this kind of thing, so it should only take a couple of minutes to try it.

Comment: @PaulR I did try to do it with gettimeofday() function and calling a wrapper with above methods several times, but was unable to draw any conclusion. I was looking for an answer which supports theoritically which one among above two is best.

Comment: I doubt there is much difference, but the important point is that if you seriously care about small differences in performance then you need to be able to accurately make benchmark comparisons. In other words, if you can't tell the difference then does it really matter? Note also that the answer may be more complex than a simple yes/no - it may be CPU-dependent, memory-access-pattern-dependent, and context-dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, you need context to say whether something will be faster or slower.  Latency, execution ports, or uop throughput (frontend) are all common bottlenecks.

If you're using 1-register addressing modes, `punpcklo` can micro-fuse with a memory operand, making the whole unpack-from-memory operation a single fused-domain uop.  If your loop is indexing into an array, instead of incrementing pointers, then go for loading 2x128b and then unpacking, since `punpcklwd xmm0, [rsi + rax]` can't micro-fuse.

Actually, scratch that.  `punpcklo` still requires its memory operand to be 16-byte aligned.  But if your source data is aligned, you could do a series of `punpcklo` / `punpckhi` pairs, with the same address.

If your intrinsics end up compiling to 4x loads and 4x unpacks, that will be at least slightly worse than 2x loads and 4x unpacks.

If you weren't limited to SSE3, SSE4.1's `PMOVZXWD xmm1, xmm2/m64` would be perfect, because it doesn't have a 128b memory operand with the corresponding alignment requirement.